# ui5 command giving error while installing ui5 in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ui5-tooling

I am trying to get started with ui5 in VS code.
I have run the following commands.

```
# Global installation to have the command available
npm install --global @ui5/cli

# Additional local install in your project
npm install --save-dev @ui5/cli

# Verify installation
ui5 --help
```

The first 2 commands run smoothly but when trying to run ui5 --help, I am getting the following error:

```
ui5 : The term 'ui5' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ui5 --version
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ui5:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What is the problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: show the content of your user and system `PATH` environment variables _in textual form please_. We need to know if the path to the directory containing your global NPM binary packages is there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update but I solved it by reinstalling nodeJS.